# How do I efficiently find out how many numbers are not divisible from a list of primes?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and in order to learn I'm trying to solve a problem as an exercise.

N is a integer between [1, 10^9]
K is a list of length <= 40 of random distinct prime numbers that are all equal or less to N.

My code has to find the quantity of number that are <= N that are not divisible by any number of the list K.

I've written the following code:

```
first_line = input().split()
second_line = input().split()


n = int(first_line[0])
list_of_primes = second_line

all_multiples_set = set()

for i in range(len(list_of_primes)):
    prime = int(list_of_primes[i])

    # Creates a set of all multiples numbers of this prime that are equal or less than N.
    one_multiple_set = set(range(prime ,n if n % prime  != 0 else n + prime ,prime ))

    # Makes a Union of this set with the previous sets of multiples, thus getting all multiples of a and b. 
    all_multiples_set = all_multiples_set.union(one_multiple_set)

print(n - len(all_multiples_set))
```

The **first input** consist of 2 numbers: N and length of K respectively. (ie. "10 3").

The **second input** is a series of length of K primes that are less or equal to N. (ie. "2 3 7").

The **output** should be a integer that represents the quantity of number equal or less than N that are not dividable by any number in list K. (ie. "2" in this case)

I know my code works for some cases, but unfortunately the [platform where I found this puzzle](https://neps.academy/problem/10) does not tell me for which cases my code does not work, it only tells me that it does not work for some cases.

I believe it is a question of memory. Given that 10^9 is a very large number, but it could also be an error that I'm not seeing.

I would appreciate some guidance in how to improve my code or a suggestion of a better approach. It is worth noticing that since this is an exercise, I can not import modules and also since I'm trying to learn, I would appreciate an explanation of why my code is ineficiente.

EDIT:

Execution time is also a factor. The code has 1 second max run time.

On my first try I wrote this code:

```
linha1 = input().split()
linha2 = input().split()


n = int(linha1[0])
s = linha2



x = len(s)

value_to_add = 0
value_to_subtract = 0


for i in range(1 << x):

    single_set = []
    multiply = 1

    for j in range(x):
        if i & (1 << j):
            single_set.append(int(s[j]))

    for num in single_set:
        multiply *= num
        if multiply > n:
            break

    if len(single_set) == 1:
        value_to_add += n//single_set[0]

    elif len(single_set) > 1:
        value_to_subtract += n//multiply

print(n - value_to_add + value_to_subtract)
```

It also gets the right answer, but it takes to long to run.

Comment: You cannot even import standard library modules?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It would be nice to hear about the possibilities I could have if I used modules in the comments.

Comment: Seems like you're doing some redundant work -- wouldn't you want to go through the set of candidates you've already tested (and shrink it at each pass) rather than starting over from scratch each time?

Comment: Ah -- yes, memory is probably the issue, and it's because you're doing the problem backwards.  :)  Instead of building a set of all the *non-matching* numbers (which will get very large) and then subtracting it from N, focus on building a set of *matching* numbers.  That'll be much more space-efficient, and should be faster as well since for each successive value of K you'll have less work to do.

Comment: Have a look at generator expressions together with the sum function and the all function or the any function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Edited]**

**Be sure to convert to int before sorting**: 
list_of_primes = list(map(int, input().split()))

I also found a way to optimize the code roughly 2x faster. Note that if in some branch **num is multiplied by min prime number** from list is larger then **N**, than there is no need to continue and branch more, since we wouldn't change **num** as it is already big enough. Therefore, the following code:

```
list_of_primes = [11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41,
                  43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101,
                  103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193]
n = 10 ** 9
list_of_primes.sort(reverse=True)
k = len(list_of_primes)
min_prime = list_of_primes[-1]


def get_count(i, num, taken):
    if num > n:
        return 0
    # if min_prime * num > n then we won't take any new numbers
    # thus taken won't change
    if min_prime * num > n or i == k:
        # the case 0 numbers taken
        if taken == 0:
            return 0
        # if odd number of numbers are taken
        if taken % 2:
            return n // num
        # if even number of numbers are taken
        return - 1 * (n // num)
    return get_count(i+1, num * list_of_primes[i], taken+1) + get_count(i+1, num, taken)


print(n - get_count(0, 1, 0))
```

is almost two times faster on the given test than the previous solution: **0.25s vs 0.63s**.

**Old solution:**

I found a way to decrease the depth of the recursion. You should iterate through **descending sorted array** of prime numbers to faster finish branching, i.e.:

```
list_of_primes.sort(reversed=True)
```

Thus in the worst case I improved the time from **5 seconds to 1.2 seconds**.

```
list_of_primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41,
                  43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101,
                  103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173]
n = 10 ** 9
list_of_primes.sort(reverse=True)
k = len(list_of_primes)


def get_count(i, num, taken):
    if num > n:
        return 0
    if i == k:
        # the case 0 numbers taken
        if taken == 0:
            return 0
        # if odd number of numbers are taken
        if taken % 2:
            return n // num
        # if even number of numbers are taken
        return -1 * (n // num)
    return get_count(i+1, num * list_of_primes[i], taken+1) + get_count(i+1, num, taken)


print(n - get_count(0, 1, 0))
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve that without recursion?

Comment: @user3347814 The short answer is no, clearly this problem should be exactly solved by recursion. If you have any troubles understanding this, try to draw on a paper how exactly the algorithm works. This usually helps me a lot.

Comment: https://neps.academy/submission/242113

I've tried publishing your solution just to see if the platform would accept it. And I'm still getting a Time Limit Exceeded error.

Comment: @user3347814 Could you provide a link to the problem? Can't see your submission.

Comment: https://neps.academy/problem/10

It is unfortunately in portuguese...

Comment: @user3347814 Can you try the same in C++? usually on online judges, the time limit is tested and adjusted for most commonly used languages. However, looking at the constraints K = 40, I believe the intended solution might be "meet in the middle". Count numbers divisible by each prime, divide the primes into two halves, compute powersets of each half, compute exclusions of products of set members, but I am unable to come up with the "meet" part i.e. how to compute exclusions of cross products of the two powersets. Intended time complexity might be O((2^(n/2))log((2^(n/2)))

Comment: @user3347814 You should try the new optimization.

Comment: @user3347814 yep the new one passes all tests.

Answer (score 4):

Since the list contains distinct prime numbers, this problem can be reduced to finding how many numbers less than or equal to `N` are divisible by these primes then deduct that number from `N`.

Since `N` can be large (10^9) and `K` is not, you can use [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to find that.

`N/x` = quantity of numbers less than or equal to `N` and are divisible by `x`

`N/(x*y)` = quantity of numbers less than or equal to `N` and are divisible by both `x` and `y` at the same time.

using inclusion exclusion principle and your sample data:

According to inclusion-exclusion, you add the number to the result when the

```
list_of_primes = [2, 3, 7]
n = 10

We add these:
10 / 2 = 5
10 / 3 = 3
10 / 7 = 1
-----------
         9
Subtract these:
10 / (2 * 3) = 1
10 / (2 * 7) = 0
10 / (3 * 7) = 0
----------------
               1
And add this:
10 / (2 * 3 * 7) = 0
--------------------
                   0

result = 9 - 1 + 0 = 8
n - result = 10 - 8 = 2 <-- this is the answer
```

You can implement that using a recursive approach as the following:

```
list_of_primes = [2, 3, 7]
n = 10
k = 3

def get_count(i, num, taken):
    if num > n:
        return 0
    if i == k:
        # the case 0 numbers taken
        if taken == 0:
            return 0
        # if odd number of numbers are taken
        if taken % 2:
            return n // num
        # if even number of numbers are taken
        return -1 * (n // num)
    return get_count(i+1, num * list_of_primes[i], taken+1) + get_count(i+1, num, taken)

print(n - get_count(0, 1, 0))
# 2
```

From wikipedia:

> Generalizing the results of these examples gives the principle of
>   inclusion–exclusion. To find the cardinality of the union of n sets:
>
> 1. Include the cardinalities of the sets.
> 2. Exclude the cardinalities of the pairwise intersections.
> 3. Include the cardinalities of the triple-wise intersections.
> 4. Exclude the cardinalities of the quadruple-wise intersections.
> 5. Include the cardinalities of the quintuple-wise intersections.
> 6. Continue, until the cardinality of the n-tuple-wise intersection is included (if n is odd) or excluded (n even).

Comment: Is there a way of achieving the same result without using recursion? I'm aware it works, but I also have a very hard time wrapping my head around it.

Comment: I thought it was possible using `bitmask`, but the thing is iterating over all subsets for `k=40` requires `2^40` iterations which will lead to time limit exceeded. In the recursive version we can take advantage of returning whenever the product is greater than `N` so we don't continue the `2^40` recursions.

Comment: @Mohd By the way, I also thought about using bitmasks, and you don't have to iterate through all 2^40, 10 numbers in your subset is already more then enough: 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19 * 23 * 29 > 10^9. Therefore you don't need any subsets larger than 9, the number of such sets is 373585603 (using sum of n choose k) which is less then 2^29. And from my experience the runtime of such solution on C++ would be < 1 second and definitely under 2 seconds on Python.

Comment: @Mike `10^8` in C++ on online judges runs in about 1 sec, which means `373585603` would take around 3 seconds which will lead to TLE

Comment: @Mohd It really depends, Sites like CodeForces can run 10^9 on 1 second for sure. The site that OP uses is waaay slower.

Comment: @Mike in Codeforces, it depends on the operations done in the iterations. Light and simple operations can pass `10^9` in 1 second because of compiler optimizations, while for problems that require heavy operations it won't. But OP is using Python which can't do anything close to that

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy for your `all_multiples_set` to grow to a number very close to 10^9, which is going to consume on the order of 40GB of memory -- more than is reasonable on most machines!  So you'll need a strategy that doesn't require you to keep track of so many numbers.

Start by getting N and K:

```
n, _ = map(int, input().split())
k = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

From there, one possible strategy would be to keep track of only the numbers that might actually match, and prune that number down as you go:

```
candidates = [c for c in range(1, n + 1) if c % k[0]]
for j in k[1:]:
    candidates = [c for c in candidates if c % j]

print(len(candidates))
```

This has the advantage of getting faster and smaller when you're going through a large K list, but it still has the space problem because you start off with a lot of candidates (e.g. if N is 10^9 and your first value of K is 2, you have 5 billion ints to keep track of, which is better than 10 billion but still too many).

The way to do this without taking up any space at all is to iterate through all the candidates from 1 to N, completely evaluate each one against each element of K, and add 1 to the count if it meets the criteria.  That way the only thing you need to keep track of is the count, and not what all the actual numbers are.

```
print(sum(
    1 if all(c % j for j in k) else 0
    for c in range(1, n+1)
))
```